# HTML: freeze horizontal-scroll-bar-position when vertical scrolling is only on parent element

Tags: html, css

I have this situation in html:

```
<div class="outer">
   <div class="inner"></div>
</div>


.outer{
  height: 300px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.inner{
  height: fit-content;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

As a result, I have parent div and child div.
The child doesn't have vertical-scroll, and if it overflow - the parent get scroll bar - this is by design and I need it to be.

The child div has only horizontal scroll, but you must scroll the parent untill you see the end of the child to have access to the horizontal scroll:

[image]

This is not good, I want the user to always see the horizontal-scroll, not only when scrolling to the end vertically.

I know this behavior is exist by default when the vertical-scroll is also on the inner div, but in this case I must the vertical one to be outer.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to add some additional clarity to your question, as there's a bit of guess work involved in determining your desired behaviour.. but if I've understood / guessed correctly, you want to turn off overflow-x so it cant be seen when you reach the bottom?

```css
.outer{
  height: 300px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  
}

.inner{
  width: 200px;
  height: fit-content;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
   <div class="inner">
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut maximus et urna vitae vulputate. Vivamus volutpat metus et erat rutrum, sit amet tincidunt sapien malesuada. Proin semper euismod vestibulum. Pellentesque eget dapibus arcu. Curabitur sit amet tempus justo. Aliquam orci ligula, molestie sit amet pulvinar condimentum, commodo ut velit. Phasellus ullamcorper viverra ipsum. Donec nec laoreet turpis, sed congue ex. Vestibulum pharetra, massa eget tristique ultrices, nibh turpis faucibus lectus, quis semper mauris turpis vel est.


   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No, I want to see the horizontal-scroller so the use will be able to scroll and see the hidden content
But I want the scroller to be shown always, so the use will not need to scroll to the end in order so see the horizontal scroller.
( I have edit my question, thanks)